# What should I do to fix this scanner-related bug?

Tags: java, exception

Even though this code compiles:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // imports the Scanner class from the java.util package

public class ScannerPractice {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner word = new Scanner("word 1 2 3 4"); // creates a new Scanner objecrt with a string as its input
    String scaStr = word.nextLine(); // converts scanner to string

    String strArr[] = new String[10];
    // as long as the scanner has another character...
    for (int i = 0; i < scaStr.length(); i++) {

        int j = 0;
        String k = "";
        // if the next token is an integer...
        if (word.hasNextInt()) {

            j = word.nextInt();
            k = String.valueOf(j);
            strArr[i] = k;

        }

        // otherwise, skip over that token
        else {

            word.next();

        }

    }

    String k = "";
    // for each character in charArr
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {

        // Accumulate each element of charArr to k
        k += " " + strArr[i];

    }
    System.out.print(k);

}
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at ScannerPractice.main(ScannerPractice.java:28)
```

The exception refers to line 28, which is:

```
word.next();
```

I have tried looking at my for loop that assigns values to the string array, but I still couldn't find the error.

I am racking my brain trying to solve this. Even a hint would be most appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation, Scanner throws that if you call `next()` and no more tokens are available.  And they aren't available because they haven't been typed yet, I think.

Comment: Your code makes no sense because you create a scanner which can handle tokens, but then iterate over a flat string.  So, do you want to tokenize using a scanner, or with a regular string?

Comment: Think about how many iterations you're going through if you are using `scaStr.length()` for your loop. If you're literally just trying to parse all the ints from your string, you could just use `word.hasNextInt()` to determine whether or not you want to keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already consumed all the strings in your `Scanner` on this line.

`String scaStr = word.nextLine();`

So, the scanner doesn't have more characteres and that's why you are getting that error.

I think you don't need to 'convert your scanner to string' in order to iterate over it. You can simply use a `while` to check if your `Scanner` has remaining characteres.

```
while(word.hasNext()) {
   int j = 0;
   String k = "";
   // if the next token is an integer...
   if (word.hasNextInt()) {
        j = word.nextInt();
        k = String.valueOf(j);
        strArr[i] = k;
   }
   // otherwise, skip over that token
   else {
       word.next();
   }
}
```

Comment: Looking back at my old code really goes a long way in showing how much better I've gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to check whether the *scanner* has any more input:

```
Scanner word = new Scanner("word 1 2 3 4");
String strArr[] = new String[10];
int i = 0;

while (word.hasNext()) {
    int j = 0;
    String k = "";

    if (word.hasNextInt()) {
        j = word.nextInt();
        k = String.valueOf(j);
        strArr[i] = k;
    }
    else {
        word.next();
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to iterate over the string you already consumed from the scanner, because then you lose the ability to match tokens.  If you wanted to use a string tokenizer you could do that, but then you can drop using the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run correctly change the input to:

```
Scanner word = new Scanner("word"+"\n"+"1"+"\n"+"2"+"\n"+"3"+"\n"+"4");
```

adding newline character solves the problem.